# Import types without the typescript compiler considering it a module (web workers)

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, web-worker, tsconfig

I have a web worker file that shares types with the rest of the typescript application. The web worker file is written in typescript as well.

`types.d.ts`

```js
export type someType = string | number
```

`search.worker.ts`

```js
import type { someType } from 'types.d.ts'

// Web worker logic
```

`app.ts`

```js
import type { someType } from 'types.d.ts'

// App logic
```

I created a separate tsconfig that selectively includes only `*.worker.ts` and `*.d.ts` files. I also excluded `worker.ts` from the main application tsconfig.

The issue is that when I run the worker tsconfig, it emits everything correctly except it treats it as a module. Now inside at the bottom of the transpiled worker.js file there is a `export {};`.

The issue is that spawning a web worker as a module is not globally supported, and it throws an error if it's there. So `exports {};` needs to be removed. I'm not sure how I can accomplish this, or if I need to use other post-bundling tools to get rid of this line.

I suspect that I'm basically telling typescript that it's a module by using that `import type { ...` line. But I don't really know how to import types otherwise.

Here is my config for tsconfig for the workers:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./assets/workers",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "target": "ES2020"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*.worker.ts",
        "./src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I suppose you could use *ambient* declaration files but I'm not a fan of having global types available everywhere.